# How to install authentication plugins in grails 3.0.1?

Tags: grails-3.0

I want to install authentication plug-in in my *grails* project so I used `grails install-plugin spring-security-core` command but is gives an error:

```
Error Command not found install-plugin 
Did you mean: install or list-plugins or plugin-info?. 
Grails version : 3.0.1
```

I am really new to *grails* so I am not able to understand how to install plug-in in it.

Answer (score 4):

In *grails 3* `install-pugin` is removed. Now it's enough to add a dependency in your projects `build.gradle` to install the desired plugin. In your case to install `spring-security-core` plugin add the dependency as follow:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.4"
   ...
}
```

And then simply run `grails run-app` and check that the plugin is installed.

Comment: I have added it under the dependencies in my `build.gradle` file (`compile "org.grails.plugins:errors:1.0"`), but when I try to start the app, it says it cannot find it under both my local m2 repository and remote repo.grails.org. I'm running Grails 3.3.10.

Answer (score 2):

`install-plugin` is now deprecated, please see the Grails documentation here for the correct way to install pluggins

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/plugins.html

Comment: According to link I used "grails create-plugin spring-security-core" but still it is giving an error : " | Error Command not found create-plugin
Did you mean: create-script or create-interceptor or create-integration-test?
"

Comment: Can you try below link
`http://spiesdavid.blogspot.in/2015/03/grails-3-app-with-security-part-1.html`

Comment: It's not deprecated, it's removed